# How to estimate RAM and CPU per Kubernetes Pod for a Spring Batch processing job?

Tags: kubernetes, spring-batch

I'm trying to estimate hardware resources for a Kubernetes Cluster to be able to handle the following scenarios:

- On a daily basis I need to read 46,3 Million XML messages 10KB each (approx.) from a queue and then insert them in a Spark instance and in a Sybase DB instance. I need to come out with an estimation of how many pods I will need to process this amount of data and how much RAM and how many vCPUs will be required per pod in order to determine the characteristics of the nodes of the cluster.  The reason behind all this is that we have some budget restrictions and we need to have an idea of the sizing before starting the corresponding development.
- The second scenario is the same as the one already described but 18,65 times bigger, i.e. 833,33 Million XML messages per day. This is expected to be the case within a couple of years.

So far we plan to use Spring Batch with partitioning steps. I need orientation on how to determine the ideal Spring Batch configuration, required RAM, and required CPU per POD, as well as the number of PODS.

I will greatly appreciate any comments from your side.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Since you are reading from a queue, a streaming solution would be more suitable than a batch solution in my opinion. I think this is the right time to carefully choose the solution as it will impact your current cost estimation as well as the long term maintenance.

Comment: Thanks @MahmoudBenHassine Any specific suggestions regarding the approach you've mentioned above?

Comment: No. I believe the only way to give a correct approximation is to proceed in an empirical way.